# Blank Fields should not be updated on database mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I have total two field ie name and email , If user tries to update only email .. it should  update only email field but not name field  . In my case its updating with blank value if we keep the input field blank . Here is the PHP code which i am using for learning purpose ..i know the code which i have provided causes sql injection but its just for my reference only .  Please let me know how to solve on this existing code, I know we to do something with if(trim($name) == '')  etc but not getting clear picture of how to implement on this code .

```
<?php

require('connections/connect.php');
$res = array();
if( $_REQUEST['tablename'] != null  &&
    $_REQUEST['idName'] != null  &&
    $_REQUEST['idValue'] != null 


){

        $tablename = $_REQUEST['tablename'] ;
        $idName = $_REQUEST['idName'] ;
        $idValue = $_REQUEST['idValue'] ;
        $name= $_REQUEST['name'] ;
        $email= $_REQUEST['email'] ;


        if (mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE $tablename  SET status = 2 ,  name= '$name' , email ='$email'  WHERE $idName = $idValue" ) ){
                    $res['done'] =false;
                $res['error'] = false;
                $res['message'] = "Verified.";
                $res['tablename'] = $tablename;
                $res['idName'] = $idName;
                $res['idValue'] = $idValue;
                $res['updateadhar'] = $updateadhar;



        }else{
                $res['done'] =true;
            $res['error'] = true;
            $res['message'] = "Try again later.";
        } 
}else{
$res['error'] = true;
$res['message'] = "Fields are missing.";
}

echo json_encode($res);


?>
```

Comment: You need to provide a check to see if $_REQUES[]  has values for name   and/or email then write  sql update that accordingly

Comment: @Mowzey, think that is what they are asking for help in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response .. How can i do the checkings ? can you please provide one example or demo on my existing code

Answer (score 0):

You can read user info in update again and check if posted emial address is empty , use your email data which you read alreay.

In this case you are sure that you are updating an exist user .

```
<?php

require('connections/connect.php');
$res = array();
if( $_REQUEST['tablename'] != null  &&
    $_REQUEST['idName'] != null  &&
    $_REQUEST['idValue'] != null 

){


        $tablename = $_REQUEST['tablename'] ;
        $idName = $_REQUEST['idName'] ;
        $idValue = $_REQUEST['idValue'] ;
        $name= $_REQUEST['name'] ;
        $email= !empty($_REQUEST['email']) ? $_REQUEST['email'] : "" ;

        //read user info here 
        // $user = getUserInfo($idValue )
        // if($email == ""){
        //    $email = $user['emial'];
        // }


        if (mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE $tablename  SET status = 2 ,  name= '$name' , email ='$email'  WHERE $idName = $idValue" ) ){
                    $res['done'] =false;
                $res['error'] = false;
                $res['message'] = "Verified.";
                $res['tablename'] = $tablename;
                $res['idName'] = $idName;
                $res['idValue'] = $idValue;
                $res['updateadhar'] = $updateadhar;



        }else{
                $res['done'] =true;
            $res['error'] = true;
            $res['message'] = "Try again later.";
        } 
}else{
$res['error'] = true;
$res['message'] = "Fields are missing.";
}

echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: Tried the above code .. still it is updating with blank value  when input field is empty ... (on database value is already present ... when  the input is blank it should not update with blank value )

Comment: @ShabarishShetty I can not understand , You have the correct data on database , if user emial is not sended by post Or it is empty , use database email value , what is going wrong with this mechanism

Answer (score 0):

```
require('connections/connect.php');
$res = array();
$check=false;

if(($_REQUEST['name'] !=null) && ($_REQUEST['email'] != null)){
    //in this case they both are set
    $check=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE $tablename  SET status = 2 ,  name= '$_REQUEST['name']' , email ='$_REQUEST['email']'  WHERE $idName ='$_REQUEST['id']' " );
}
else if(($_REQUEST['name'] !=null) && ($_REQUEST['email'] == null)){
    //only name is set
    $check=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE $tablename  SET status = 2 ,  name= '$_REQUEST['name']'  WHERE $idName ='$_REQUEST['id']' " );

}else if(($_REQUEST['name'] ==null) && ($_REQUEST['email'] != null)){
    //only email is set
     $check=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE $tablename  SET status = 2 , email ='$_REQUEST['email']'  WHERE $idName ='$_REQUEST['id']' " );
}


if (!$check){
    $res['done'] =false;
    $res['error'] = false;
    $res['message'] = "Verified.";
    $res['tablename'] = $tablename;
    $res['idName'] = $idName;
    $res['idValue'] = $idValue;
    $res['updateadhar'] = $updateadhar;
}else{
    $res['done'] =true;
    $res['error'] = true;
    $res['message'] = "Try again later.";
} 


echo json_encode($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this codes

```
<?php
require('connections/connect.php');
$res = array();
if(!is_null($_REQUEST['tablename']) && !is_null($_REQUEST['idName']) && !is_null($_REQUEST['idValue'])){
    if(!empty(trim($_REQUEST['name'])) && !empty(trim($_REQUEST['email']))){
        $tablename = $_REQUEST['tablename'] ;
        $idName = $_REQUEST['idName'] ;
        $idValue = $_REQUEST['idValue'] ;
        $name= trim($_REQUEST['name']);
        $email= trim($_REQUEST['email']) ;
        $sql = "UPDATE `{$tablename}`SET status = 2, name= '{$name}', email ='{$email}' WHERE `{$idName}` = '{$idValue}'";
        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
            $res = array_merge(array('done' => false, 'error' => false, 'message' => 'Verified.', 'updateadhar' => $updateadhar), compact('tablename','idName','idValue'));
        }else{ $res = array('done' = true, 'error' => true, 'message' => "Try again later."); }
    }else{ $res = array('error' => true, 'message' => "Name/Email are missing."); }
}else{ $res = array('error' => true, 'message' => "Fields are missing."); }
echo json_encode($res);
?>
```